# playframework with Twirl views not found: value

Tags: scala, playframework, twirl

i pass a lot of time trying to solve very simple problem render à string or(List) from controller to view using playframework java and Twirl, my code here

in my controller

```
  public Result list(){
            //List<String>  todo = Arrays.asList("sup1","sup2","sup3");
            String nana = "coco";
            return ok(index.render(nana));
        }
```

in my view

```
@(message: String)
@(nana:String)

@main("Welcome to Play") {

    @play20.welcome(message, style = "Java")
    <h1>@nana</h1>


}
```

so there are the some configuration for Twirl or automatically ? anyone help me to render data to view and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the error you're seeing? What are the full blocks of code, with all imports?

The syntax seems to be all wrong:

- Your template should only have one parameter declaration, which is the `@(...)` line at the top. If you want to pass in two values, you should write `@(message: String, nana: String)` at the top of your template. And then you need to pass values for both in when you call `index.render(message, nana)`.
- I'm not sure what `@main` refers to, since imports aren't listed, but you should try getting it to work first without that block. Render a plain string, then add in some variables, then maybe try for a fancy callback like `@main`.